# Is the "algebraic closure" of the quaternions, finite dimensional?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, quaternions

This post is a sequel of: [What's the algebraic closure of the quaternions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1071874/84284)

$\mathbb{H}$ is algebraically closed for the polynomials of the form $\sum a_r x^r$, but **it is not** for the polynomials freely generated by $\mathbb{H}$ and $x$ (because $xi+ix-j$ has no root), and it admits a "formal" algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1071880/84284)).

*Question*: Is $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$   finite dimensional over $\mathbb{H}$? If so, what's this dimension?

*Remark*: If $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ is an associative division algebra over the real, then it must be infinite dimensional, thanks to the [Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)).

Comment: The definition of $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ given in that answer is problematic (see my comments there); it is not obvious to me that there exists any nonzero $\mathbb{H}$-algebra in which every noncommutative polynomial over $\mathbb{H}$ has a root.

Comment: According to @EricWofsey, the existence of such a closure need to be validated. Of course if it's invalidated, the current version of the question doesn't makes sense, but then, we could restrict to a subclass of polynomials, for example those with terms of the form $ax^nb$. I'll wait a confirmation a few days, before an eventual update of the question.

Comment: The right notion to look at is probably [existentially closed](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Existentially_closed).